# [PHP] Как убить полностью аутенфикацию через header?

Tags: php, auth

Привет народ! Кто знает как убить аутентификацию через header не выходя из браузера?
У меня есть стандартная аутентификация через

```
Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Hello, world!.\"");
```

и переменные

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']   
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']
```

я пытаюсь их стереть спомощь `unset();`
Но после этого они всеравно появляются или я что то не так делаю? 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо отправить статус 401

> header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

Comment: ahha спасибо работает